# WinRT/C++ std::thread vs winrt::resume_background()

Tags: multithreading, c++-winrt, winrt-async

After studying `std::thread`, I know that a function can be run on a different thread than the main thread, which is similar to the concept of `winrt::resume_background()` which will continue executing code on another thread (ThreadPool).

So the questions are,

1. Can `std::thread` replace `winrt::resume_background()`?
2. Can `std::thread` be used for a function that will update the UI on a desktop application with WinRT/C++ libraries directly without having to manually revert it on the UI thread?

Because if all these things are possible, then of course this can be a solution to all the `co_await`ing problems and wrong threads.

Comment: You cannot make changes to the UI from a thread other than the thread that created the UI. Of course, you *could* call `CoreDispatcher::RunAsync` from a `std::thread`. Though it's unclear why you would want to go **back** to manual thread management.

Comment: The co_await machinery was primarily intended to make it easy to run code asynchronously, then resume executing on the caller thread so it is simple to update UI.  Inspired in no small part by WinRT, a heavily async framework that makes such a feature important to create programs without getting seriously stranded in threading-hell.  You'll specifically won't get that feature from using std::thread, if you are in hell now with co_await then you're pretty likely to get in much deeper.